# If $-3<a<5$ then $\boxed{?}<a^2<\boxed{?}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $-3<a<5$ then $\boxed{?}<a^2<\boxed{?}$

My try: We know that if $0<a<b<d$ then $0<a^2<b^2<d^2$

So $0<a+3<8$ => $0<(a+3)^2<8^2$

But then when I extend $(a+3)^2$ I can't solve

So I need some hint!

This is from an exercise that asks you to round $a^2+b^2$ given $-3<a<5$ and $2<b<4$

Comment: If $-3 < a < 5$ then $ 0 \leq |a| < 5$ so $0 \leq a^2 < 5^2 = 25$.

Comment: It's not wrong to write $-100<a^2<100$ for example but the optimal inequalities are  given by Svinepels

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The square of any real number must be $\geq 0$. So we know that $a=0$ is a possibility, we have $0\leq a^2 <?$. We need only find what $?$ is. Notice that $a^2=|a||a|$, so only the 'size' of the number matters. What is the biggest $a$ can be? Well, that is $a=5$ (not technically as $a=5$ is not a choice but we know we 'fix' this by choosing $<$ rather than $\leq$ when we square). Therefore, 
$$
0 \leq a^2 <25
$$

Comment: I presume you mean "$a=5$ is not a choice".

Comment: @barto Yes! Thank you, I have no idea why I typed $1$. I shall fix this.

Answer (score 3):

$\begin{eqnarray}{\bf Hint}\quad    a\ &\in& (-3,0\,] \cup [\,0,5)\\
\Rightarrow \ a^2 &\in& (\,\  9,\ 0\,] \cup [\,0,25) = [0,25)\end{eqnarray}$

Comment: It's $25)$, not $25]$, If I see good.

Comment: @Cortizol Yes, fixed, thanks.

Comment: $(9,0]$ is not standard notation.

Comment: @Carsten Was its meaning not clear, and helpful in understanding the proof?

Comment: The OP is a beginner, and others may expect more exact notation of him.

Comment: @Carsten There is nothing "inexact" about that notation.

Comment: The usual definition is $(a,b]=\{x\colon a<x\le b\}$.

Comment: @Carsten Of course I know that. There are hundreds if not thousands of extensions/variants/abuses? of "standard" notations that are in frequent use. One should not be afraid to use them, esp. if it helps to clarify a proof. The above is a rather trivial example of such (less trivial examples are found in many of my posts). It is hard to imagine that a reader cannot quickly and accurately infer the intended denotation above. What else could it possibly mean given the context?

Comment: I was only mentioning it because of the OP's apparent level. What he writes may after all be graded by people with a less nonchalant view of this notation. But I see an actual danger here: it is easy to mistake $(9,0]\cup[0,25)$ for $(9,25)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$0\leq|a|^2<3^2$$ and $$0\leq|a|^2<5^2$$ 
Then
$0\leq a^2<25$

Comment: I think you meant $|a|^2=a^2$ in the middle inequalities. I fixed the bottom one as there I believe you meant $0 \leq a^2<25$ not $0 \leq a <25$.

Comment: You use *or* incorrectly.

Comment: I meant *and*...